# Import Image Python (MyImage)

Tags: python, image, import

Hello everyone I'm a total beginner in Python and would like to do a analyses of grey scale pictures. I found a tutorial at which the MyImage Modul is used.
I did install the modul via pip install myimage
and use the following code for the start:

```
from myimage import*
img = myimage('Example.png')
```

However it says that myimage (here in line 2) is not defined...
Does anyone know this problem?

Comment: What tutorial are you following? Looks like you should be calling a function in the myimage module instead of my image itself.

Comment: Its a short introduction into Python and MyImage where it says that I can import the image like shown...I can provide you the link my it helps even its in german: http://www.mevis-research.de/~richard/sommer-akademie2011/html/img-tutorial1

Comment: I don't know about this package, and it seems that there's no documentation online. What is it exactly that you are trying to achieve? You can probably do it with other image manipulation libraries like [Pillow](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) or [OpenCV](https://opencv.org/), which are very well documented and have a large community of users, so it will be easier to debug any issues that you have.